# Edit Value of Column if Empty

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to edit the contents of a CSV file where column 4 (`$4`) has a header of `default_address`. Currently, the column is empty, aside from the header. I would like to use AWK to edit the value of the column to `Y` if the value is null (blank). I'm probably way off base here, but this is what I was trying:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," }; {if ($4="") $4="Y"; print}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks almost sound enough. You could combine F and OFS into the BEGIN statement; the semicolon after BEGIN is not necessary ...  you're doing an assignment in the if, and there's `{}` missing around the statement behind the `if`? How about sample data?

Comment: Your code looks pretty on base, except for one small thing.  Instead of `if ($4="")` use two `==` to test for equality: `if ($4 == "")`.  If that doesn't work, update your question with a few lines of sample input and expected output.

Comment: Your answer is correct, except what @jas pointed out. `($4="") -> ($4=="")`. In general I would write it as `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}($4==""){$4="Y"}1'`

Comment: I voted to close this question as it is only a typographical error which is addressed in the comments.

Comment: Thank you all.  I will test this out tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," }; {if ($4="") $4="Y"; print}' file1.csv > file2.csv

This will get you there:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {OFS=","} $4 == "" { $4 = "Y" }  {print}' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Take care with `==` versus `=`, and prefer the awk pattern to `if`
when it does what you need.  Your `if` is missing braces, which might
have been part of your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will test tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Completely worked.  Thank you all :-)